# There is a problem occured to me during learning firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

WARNING in configuration
The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value.
Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.
You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior.

i dont know what to expect.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't explicitly set the 'mode' option in your Webpack configuration, and as a result, Webpack will use a default mode, which is 'production' in this case.

here is the official documentation:https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/